# Connect a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

I'm trying to connect a gesture to a UIView so I can tap on the object, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Shape.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Shape : UIView; 

- (id) initWithX: (int)xVal andY: (int)yVal;

@end
```

Shape.m

```
#import "Shape.h"

@implementation Shape 

- (id) initWithX:(int )xVal andY:(int)yVal {
    self = [super init];    
    UIView *shape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 10, 10)];
    shape.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shape.userInteractionEnabled = YES;     
    [self addSubview:shape];
    return self;
}

@end
```

MODIFIED CODE: The following code is in the main ViewController. I have removed the UITapGestureRecognizer from the Shape class. The code works if I make the following change, but then it is 'box' that responds to the tap gesture, not 'shape':
[shape addGestureRecognizer:tap];
to 
[box addGestureRecognizer:tap];

```
- (void)handlerTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
-(void)drawShapes{
    NSLog(@"Draw");
    if(!box){
        box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight-100)];
        box.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.8 green: 0.8 blue: 0.0 alpha:0.2];
        [self.view addSubview:box];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        int x = arc4random() % screenWidth;
        int y = arc4random() % screenHeight;
        Shape * shape =[[Shape alloc] initWithX:x andY:y ];
        [box addSubview:shape];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(handlerTap:)];
        [box addGestureRecognizer:tap];     
    }
}
```

SOLUTION: I have learned that 
self = [super init]; 
needs to be changed to include a CGRECT that defines the boundaries of the view that *shape is placed into. 
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 10, 10)];

Also, *shape needs to be placed at 0,0 to ensure its correct placement within its parent.
UIView *shape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];

```
#import "Shape.h"

@implementation Shape 

- (id) initWithX:(int )xVal andY:(int)yVal {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 10, 10)];    
    UIView *shape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    shape.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shape.userInteractionEnabled = YES;     
    [self addSubview:shape];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: you're not setting shape's frame anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the target of the gesture recognizer to `self`, not the view, because you implemented the `handlerTap:` method in the `Shape` class.

Comment: I tried changing the target on each of the lines below, and then together, but the gesture still does not work.
 [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(handlerTap:)];
 [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Comment: No, you need to add the gesture recognizer to the view and set the target to self.

Comment: I edited my code to do what I think you told me, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you set it's frame? You just call `[super init]` and don't set the frame. The default is `CGRectZero` I think.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Why do I have to set the frame and where/ how do I do this?

Comment: How do you present the Shape view? You have to initialize it somewhere and set it's frame, right?

Comment: I have made a change as described in 'MODIFIED CODE' above. Let me know if you need a better description.

Comment: The Shape's frame is never set as far as I see. It will be zero and thus invisible.

Comment: I am not having a problem making the content of the Shape visible. Each shape draws a box into the containing View (i.e. [box addSubview:shape];) My problem is that I cannot add an event handler that allows me to respond each time the user touches a Shape.

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks DrummerB.